# How can I make a mail server with node js

Tags: node.js, express, email, mail-server

I am trying to make a mail server and all the ones I find do not meet my needs. I would like a mail server with no dashboard or built-in email site. I just want something that I can make a request like POST *domain*/createEmail with a body with auth key name and stuff like that. I also want  it to integrate with some systems I already have. I was wondering if it would be possible to do this in node-js and expressjs. I am willing to use an api or library. I have asked chat-gpt and it says that it is un-practical. I do not need it to be practical I need it to work with what I have. If you could help me find a library and guide me on how to use it, it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi, this type of request is off-topic here. In the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you can find a section that explains what we should not ask here. Thank you!